# How to move a file to another folder in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Given the file tree:

```
x/y/a.txt
```

How do I move the file up to:

```
x/a.txt
```

When right clicking on the file I just see delete and rename but not the move command.
A google search did not reveal anything about this.
I use `vscode 1.6.1`

Update: It is currently impossible to move files and folders to the root folder: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1043

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use drag n' drop to move the file

Comment: NIce :-) .How do i move a file to the root folder of the project?

Comment: Drag n drop doesn't work for me, it prompts me, I click move but it doesn't actually do anything, I tried multiple times, with different files and folders. And I'm not even trying to move it to root folder, it's a sub. @DavidMichaelGang Drag n drop is enabled as well, just checked in settings

Comment: Never mind I closed vscode and opened it again and it worked. It was running for too long (I don't shutdown my laptop)

Comment: How to make SVN understand the move?

Answer (score 27):

Move is available by right-clicking the file in the sidebar after installing [File Utils](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sleistner.vscode-fileutils) from the Visual Studio Code Marketplace.

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone that's turned off drag and drop. I found a feature request for the menu option and the response was "use an extension". https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61870

Comment: This is the way. Works just like in sublime command palette: duplicate, move, rename, etc.

Comment: that extension even creates folders if they don't exist, like a proper text editor should do. As @Merlin said, this is the way.

Answer (score 10):

You can also move file with using console (for example PowerShell or Git Bash) in Code.

Recently I have I habit to move files or folders in sidebar, via ctrl + x (cut) and ctrl + v (paste), after this action Code automatically updates imports.

Drag & drop method also works.

Answer (score 6):

The OP [issue 1043](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1043) which was resolved with VSCode v1.37 (2019)

That feature is still improving, with [issue 98309](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98309): "Support multiple files in working copy file service".
See [PR 98988](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/98988) "File operation events support multiple resources"

That allows other files which depends on the move to be properly updated when you are moving *several* files.
That will avoid this:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1078012/82544280-d0bba680-9b4c-11ea-84ca-aafda0c68486.gif]